# complex query with max();

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  GENRE,MAX(COUNT(GENRE)) 
FROM BOOKS
WHERE ID_BOOK IN(SELECT ID_BOOK 
                 FROM SIGNATURES
                 WHERE SIGNATURE IN(SELECT SIGNATURE 
                                    FROM ORDERS 
                                    WHERE ID_READER=1))
GROUP BY GENRE;
```

I get an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

When I delete GENRE which stays just after SELECT it works okay but produces only number. I also need to know which specific GENRE has maximum value.

EDIT:

```
select GENRE,CNT INTO var_genre, var_max from (
SELECT GENRE,COUNT(GENRE) as CNT FROM BOOKS
WHERE ID_BOOK IN(SELECT ID_BOOK FROM SIGNATURES
WHERE SIGNATURE IN(SELECT SIGNATURE FROM ORDERS WHERE ID_READER=1))
GROUP BY GENRE
order by COUNT(GENRE) desc)
where rownum < 2;
```

Comment: If the `MAX(COUNT(genre))` needs the highest count within the entire set, you just need to add `OVER ()` to indicate the full-set window.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do tow aggregations in one query. you should do it in subquery:

```
select distinct GENRE,CNT from ( 
  select GENRE,CNT, DENSE_RANK() Over(prder by CNT) as rnk from (
    SELECT GENRE,
           COUNT(GENRE) over (partition by GENRE) as CNT
      FROM BOOKS
     WHERE ID_BOOK IN(SELECT ID_BOOK 
                       FROM SIGNATURES
                       WHERE SIGNATURE IN(SELECT SIGNATURE FROM ORDERS WHERE ID_READER=1))
)
whre rnk = 1;
```

Or if you need only one row you may wrap it into subquery:

```
select GENRE,CNT from (
SELECT GENRE,COUNT(GENRE) as CNT FROM BOOKS
WHERE ID_BOOK IN(SELECT ID_BOOK FROM SIGNATURES
    WHERE SIGNATURE IN(SELECT SIGNATURE FROM ORDERS WHERE ID_READER=1))
GROUP BY GENRE
order by COUNT(GENRE) desc)
whre rownum < 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much but when I try to execute this code using SQL Plus with modification - select GENRE, CNT INTO var1, var2 FROM... I receive error ORA-01403. Is it possible to run this from the level of SQL Plus?

Comment: Its query will return the same result in SQL plus and in any  other IDE. ORA-01403 - it means no_data_found query not return any row

Comment: Well, this code works perfectly fine on SQL Developer and gives a proper result but on SQL Plus I see this error and I'm pretty sure that data is still in the DB.

Comment: No miracles. If the same query return different result ot means 3 posibilities: 1) you check in different databases 2) you insert or delete or update rows and not commited 3) your query are not the same

Comment: 1),2) - not true
3) - true with modification I wrote a few posts before. This modification is needed by pl/sql standard. Maybe I have sth mistaken changing it?

Comment: Could you please add your new query into your original post?